# How to setup concurrency token/row version with Entity Framework 5 in Postgres?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have an entity in EF Core & I use `xmin` for concurrency check:

```
public class Car {
    public Guid  ID { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public uint xmin { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I configure `OnModelCreating` in DataContext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>(
                b => {
                    // Properties
                    b.Property(nameof(Car.ID)).IsRequired();
                    // Concurrency setting
                    b.UseXminAsConcurrencyToken();
                    // Primary Key
                    b.ToTable("cars").HasKey(nameof(Car.ID));
                });
```

I can see the `xmin` column in the Postgres table, which is good.

Now I backup the `cars` database using `pg_dump` & restore the database back with `pg_restore`
The values in `xmin` column in the restored `cars` database are different from the ones before I ran the backup, which is a problem as it has messed up with other system which depends on that `xmin` value in `cars` database.

I am aware it is impossible to backup & restore `xmin` value from Postgres database. So I could not use `UseXminAsConcurrencyToken`, unless I have missed out something here.

How do I do a proper row-version/concurrency check with Entity Framework Core & Postgres which can be persisted & restored in a database backup?

Comment: Cross-posted on github as https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2069, conversation ongoing there.